# Jenkins/Hudson the best way to delete remote git branch after build

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm  trying to find the best way to delete git remote branch after Jenkins build.
At our environment we have separate job for sanity-check branch before merging this branch to master repository. So branch became not useful after successful Jenkins job's build.
I may be wrong but it seems that there are no such built-in functionality in Git Plugin. And I should use something like:

```
git push origin :branchName;
```

Sanity job poll branch for build using some mask so if there is any variable for branch name in Git plugin which can be used? - Seems it is possible to use ${GIT_BRANCH}.

`git push ${GIT_BRANCH/\// :}`

Also as I understand I can call this command only at build time(not using post-build actions) as workaround call other job with delete functionality?

Update: for script can be used:

```
branch_name=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`; git push origin :$branch_name
```

Comment: I think I don't understand your work process basing on your description. If you are creating a temporary 'sanity-check branch' and if it is not needed later, then I understand that you would not want that temporary branch to stay visible at the normal list of branches. However, I don't understand **why is that temporary branch visible at all**. If your build process creates that temporary branch, merges on it and builds on it, then it's **all local** to the builder. The temporary branch should simply not be "pushed" to the main repository by the build process.

Comment: Or maybe you are creating that sanitycheck branch manually each time? if so - then why? can't it be automated at the startup of the build process?

Comment: I mean, if the build process made the branch automatically and locally, everything on Git side would work just as normal (local unpublished branch is still a normal branch!), the temp-branch would not be visible at main repository, and after the build process finishes, it would simply evaporate along with the temp directory into which the code was cloned for build..

Comment: Thank you, we have such uncomfortable flow and really have no choice of changing it. It is smth like:
- changes in local branch

Comment: -push changes to repository temp branch
-some jenkins jobs poll temp branches by mask(product version)
-if build success developer rebase team-master branch to upstream/master
-developer chery-pick changes to team-master from his local branch
-developer force push team-master branch to repository


So as we cannot change smth in common. We just want to automate cleaning temp branch from repository.